# Using JQuery to change CSS in the master page works, but then reverts back to the default value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-pages, document-ready

This is how I have my HTML setup.

```
<ul id="nav" class="nav">
  <li id="home"><a href="/Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
  <li id="ocr"><a href="/tools/ocr.aspx">OCR</a></li>
  <li id="contact"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

And my JQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#nav li').click(function () {
            $('#nav li').removeClass();
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

If I add a "return false", to stop the page from loading, it works just fine. But of course the page doesn't load. When it runs normally, the JQuery fires and then the value is reverted back to the default page.

Since the JQuery fires when the ListItem is clicked, and not when the page loads, the master page loads and the change is reverted.

Any ideas on how to best accomplish this with a masterpage? I changed to JQuery because I couldn't get the JS working, which was probably due to the masterpage issue.

Comment: So you would like to go to a new page, but update the CSS on the page you are leaving, and keep those changes? And what is a "masterpage" ?

Comment: one way is to use cookies...

Comment: @adeneo This is ASP.NET. [Masterpage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: welcome..link to jquery cookies https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie